# Design pattern for activity state controll

Tags: android

I have an actvivity which contain several fragments and views. When I started working on my app the activity had several states which I changed throw click listeners in fragments and views.

Currently the code grew up to >1.5k lines and I realize that I need to introduce some pattern to make it maintainable.
The problem is that when I change my activitie's property I need to change layout in several fragments or views.

For example I have a handler which listens to network response:

```
//Handler to process messages from VendorCache
    private Handler vendorCacheHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == VendorCache.RECEIVED_OPTIONS){

                String id = (String)msg.obj;

                vendorOptionsManager = new VendorOptionsManager(id);

                detailsPagerAdapter.updateOptions(vendorOptionsManager.isPickupTime(), vendorOptionsManager.hasOptions());

                //Update Optional/Required labels
                updateDestinationReqs();

                //Enable/disable quote button depending on the pickupSite and booking options
                checkQuoteStateAndUpdate();

                if(pendingOrderOptions != null && pendingOrderOptions.size() > 0 && vendorOptionsManager != null){                      
                    //Spinner is hidden and options are populated with new values
                    detailsPagerAdapter.updateOptionsView(VendorUtils.getReadableString(pendingOrderOptions,vendorOptionsManager.getAllOptions()), getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color_main));
                }

            }
            else if(msg.what == VendorCache.MALFORMED_ID || msg.what == VendorCache.REQUEST_FAILED){
                vendorOptionsManager = null;

                //Update Optional/Required labels
                updateDestinationReqs();



                //Enable quote button
                taskBar.setQuoteEnabled(true);

                //Disable any options
                detailsPagerAdapter.updateOptions(false, false);
            }

        }
    };
```

As you can see methods in handler change layout in views or fragment. Drawback is that I need to call the same methods with different params depending on the response. Similar situation occurs for other activity properties.

I am not saying that my activity is overloaded with views. I am saying that I have several properties that are interconnected. For example if property A=true and B= true then C="required" or if A=true and B = false then C = "optional" etc. Because of that I have a lot of calls to similar methods.

I am thinking of introducing ActivityStateController class which will implement Observer pattern. This will allow me to hide state management inside views and fragments. But I still doubt about that(e.g. what to do to show progress in views?)

What are the ways to manage complex activity state? Is there something similar to key value coding in Android or Java?